# CSS transition based on conditional class changing doesn't work using vuejs and tailwind

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use the **tailwind** `transition` class to expand a `<router-link>` submenu inside a sidebar **Vuejs** component.

```
// template

<div
    :class="`${index === 0 ? 'mt-2' : ''} sidebar-link sidebar-dropdown-link`"
    @click="link.open = !link.open"
>
    <div class="flex items-center">
        <FontAwesomeIcon
            :icon="link.icon"
            class="sidebar-link-icon"
        />
        {{ link.label }}
    </div>
    <FontAwesomeIcon
        :icon="link.open ? ['fas', 'chevron-up'] : ['fas', 'chevron-down']"
        class="sidebar-dropdown-link-icon"
    />
</div>

// This is the funny line...
<div :class="`${link.open ? `h-[${link.sublinks.length * 45}px]` : 'h-0'} sidebar-dropdown-menu`">
    <router-link
        v-for="(sublink, index) in link.sublinks"
        :key="index" class="sidebar-link mt-1"
        :to="sublink.route"
    >
        <FontAwesomeIcon
            :icon="sublink.icon"
            class="sidebar-link-icon pl-3"
        />
        {{ sublink.label }}
    </router-link>
</div>
```

The expected behavior is that when `link.open` turns to `true` the `<div>` tag defined in the **funny line** is unfolded (or shown) with a 300ms transition and its `height` value has been defined based on `link.sublinks.length` value, all of this applying `sidebar-dropdown-menu` CSS class. I mean:

```
.sidebar-dropdown-menu { @apply w-full overflow-hidden transition-[height] duration-[300ms] }
```

If `link.sublinks.length` is equal to `3` the applying custom class would be `h-[135px]` and the `<div>` tag in the **funny line** show up, however the tansition is not working although `p-0` class is working as expencted. Google Chrome Dev Tools show me `height: 135px` as a disabled CSS rule.

Finanlly if I replace `h-[${link.sublinks.length * 45}px]` for a costant value (like `h-[200px]` for instance) everything work as expected.

I suspect `h-auto` is overwriting my height custom class.

I'm latin so my english is not very good looking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to apply a transition on height, both of the height value should be in the same unit, if it's `135px` after expanding, it should be `0px` or any `px` value that you desire when collapsed. Note that the `auto` value does not have the transition effect.

Comment: @Towkir I used ```link.open ? `h-[${link.sublinks.length * 45}px]` : 'h-[0px]'``` but it still not working, I think the issue is about the ```auto``` value which is taken over the calculated class.

Comment: then somehow your style is being overwritten, try to make your styles more specific, you can check css style precedence or specificity to know how.

Comment: @fahico98 Your class is [dynamic](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#classes-aren-t-generated). Safelist all possible values or use style binding as you did already (not sure why you don't like it)

Answer (score 2):

I've achieve to make it work but I didn't like the solution I found:

```
<div
    :style="`${link.open ? `height: ${link.sublinks.length * 45}px` : 'height: 0px'}`"
    class="sidebar-dropdown-menu"
>
```

Just avoid to use **Tailwind** classes to define the height attribute, that's it for now.